# Using jquery UI along with mvc helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I want to use JQuery UI datepicker  along with the ASP:NET MVC helper. Here is the source code of my View: My question is that, how can I use the @Html.Editorfor line as a jquery UI dropdownlist? Thanks in advance.

These parts omitted for brevity:

```
        <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label>Memuriyete başlangıç tarihiniz nedir? </label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi,null, new { id = "drpMemuriyetBaslama" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi)
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#drpMemuriyetBaslama").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Scripts references are put in _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/MenuStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="title">Lojman Bilgi Sistemi</div>
    </div>
    <div id="categories">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the sample use of datepicker: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#animation

Comment: You forgot to write your question!

Comment: Unless you using MVC-5.1 or higher, you cannot add html attributes using `EditorFor()` (and if you are, you doing it wrong anyway). Remove the `new { id = "drpMemuriyetBaslama" }` and use the default `id` attribute `$("#MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi").datepicker();` or use `TextBoxFor()` is there is some specific reason to override the default `id` attribute generated by the helper

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write my question.

Comment: Thank you Mr Stephen Muecke. I want to set your answer as a true answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi, null, new { id = "drpMemuriyetBaslama" })
```

is not generating an element with `id="drpMemuriyetBaslama"` so that

```
$("#drpMemuriyetBaslama").datepicker();
```

will throw an error because `$("#drpMemuriyetBaslama")` is undefined

Unless your using MVC-5.1 or higher, you cannot add html attributes using the `EditorFor()` method, and if your are, then the syntax needs to be

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "drpMemuriyetBaslama" } })
```

All the HtmlHelpers that generate form controls add a default `id` attribute based on the property name (in your case it will be `id="MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi"`) so unless you have a specific reason for changing it, then you can simply use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi)
```

and

```
$("#MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi").datepicker();
```

alternatively, if you want to change the default `id` attribute, use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi, new { id = "drpMemuriyetBaslama" })
```